# How to make Tortoisesvn 1.8 work with windows 7

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using TortoiseSVN client version 1.8 to check out and check in files into repository.But i am getting errors timeout/internal malfunction after sonmetime(by then some jsp and jar files are downloaded).

Can someone please help me with steps i need to follow to make it work with windows 7?

and

Is there a better alternative to TortoiseSVN which can be used as a clinet?

Comment: For timeouts the real reason might be your internet speed or the way the admin has set up the repository (eg. master slave config where both of them are different locations with low internet speed). I think best is to contact the admin of svn repository you are using and let him know about the frequent errors

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better alternative to TortoiseSVN which can be used as a clinet?

If you are using an IDE, check out plugins for working with version control systems. (a.k.a. Team Synchronization, Collaboration, etc.) Sometimes it can be real time saver.